Where can I deploy a Program MVP without having to pay?
We created a project to be deployed but we are stuck with deploying it to the mainnet, like we are unable to fund our wallets with sol and if we want to buy we have to complete EDD, like wth I don't even work I don't file an ITR, I am still 21 and studying, yet we cannot find a way to fund our wallets and also when we received the grant application reply mail it wasn't a complete rejection like they sent us a mail saying "the idea is a good one, but we need an MVP and if you are done with that we will consider your application for a grant" is this kind of an email a common thing like a common rejection email or does everybody get the same thing?
How are we supposed to deploy the smart contracts, we have 6 smart contracts to be deployed and the cost is around 0.4 sol, but how can I get funded with my wallet to deploy it?
Are there any other ways where we can raise funds of 2 sol from anywhere? If so please help us?

For an MVP, you can deploy your program on devnet to start. This is a testing environment where SOL is free. You can get some by using the solana cli:
solana airdrop <how much sol you want> <your pubkey in base58>

